# Parameterizing superclass with static member class from subclass

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to parameterize a superclass with a static member class of the subclass?

#### Contrived Example

*ExampleSuperClass.java*:

```java
package foo;

public class ExampleSuperClass<T> {
    protected T field;
    
    public ExampleSuperClass(T field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public T getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

*ExampleSubClass.java*:

```java
package foo;

public class ExampleSubClass extends ExampleSuperClass<Member> {

    static class Member {
    
    }
    
    public ExampleSubClass() {
        super(new Member());
    }
}
```

Compilation fails on `ExampleSubClass.java` with error:

> ```
> [javac] ExampleSubClass.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
> [javac] public class ExampleSubClass extends ExampleSuperClass<Member> {
> [javac]                                                        ^
> [javac]   symbol: class Member
> [javac] 1 error
> ```

or in Eclipse with:

> Member cannot be resolved to a type

in Eclipse the `super` invocation also has the error:

> The constructor ExampleSuperClass(Member) refers to missing type Member

It works fine (aka no errors) if ExampleSubClass is instead parameterized with another package-protected top-level class.

#### Summary

The driving force behind this is that I have a generic super class and many different `${SubClass-extends-GenericSuperClass}.java` and `${ClassUsedBySubClass}.java` pairs. But since `ClassUsedBySubClass` is only ever referenced by `SubClass`, it would be nice to:

1. restrict `ClassUsedBySubClass`'s access by making it a static member class and
2. cut down on the number of files by not giving `ClassUsedBySubClass` its own file.

So, is there a way to use a subclass's member class in parameterizing the superclass?

If there isn't -- is there an alternative approach?

Comment: Have you tried `ExampleSuperClass<ExampleSubClass.Member>` ? Not sure if that would help in any way ... just curious. Meaning: use the "real" name of that inner class?

Comment: wow yeah that did work -- as simple as that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. However, since Java uses the scope *outside* the declaration for name resolution, you must qualify `Member` with the name of `ExampleSubClass`:

```
public class ExampleSubClass extends ExampleSuperClass<ExampleSubClass.Member> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I should really resist the urge to write down answers as comments ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Well, I wasn't 100% certain that the answer was going to work, so I went off to ideone and tried it out before writing an answer. I reasoned that whatever deserves a trip to ideone also deserves to be an answer :-)

Comment: Interesting. Out of curiousity --> Do you have any idea why `... extends ExampleSuperClass<Member>` (without the qualification) won't work even if the `ExampleSuperClass` explicitly imports it with `import foo.ExampleSubClass.Member`? Shouldn't `Member` then be visible to the superclass?

Comment: @xgord importing `Member` explicitly changes visibility inside superclass. The declaration, however, is at the top level, so the name is still not visible on the outside, even though it's visible inside the subclass.

Answer (score 8):

Because `Member` is an inner class, you need to specify that when using it as a generic type.  I'm able to get it to compile by using the following:

```
static class ExampleSubClass extends  ExampleSuperClass<ExampleSubClass.Member> {
    static class Member {

    }

    public ExampleSubClass() {
        super(new Member());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Member` is a static nested class. Static [nested](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) class is accessed using the enclosing class name:

```
ExampleSubClass.Member
```

You do this every time a static nested class occurs outside the scope of its outer class.

Therefore, the following is correct:

```
public class ExampleSubClass extends ExampleSuperClass<ExampleSubClass.Member> {
                                                              ^
                                                     enclosing class name
    static class Member {
        ...
    }
}
```

Same as when you want to create an object for the static nested class:

```
ExampleSubClass.Member member = new ExampleSubClass.Member();
```